# SQL Query doesn't run as intended(between)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query(in postgresql),

```
select distinct 
    "bookings"."memberId" 
from "shifts" 
inner join "bookings" 
on "bookings"."shiftId" = "shifts"."id" 
where "shifts"."startTime" not between '2016-01-02 00:00:00.000' and '2020-01-01 23:59:59.999' 
    and "shifts"."startTime" >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
    and "shifts"."startTime" <= '2016-01-01 23:59:59.999' 
    and "bookings"."state" in ('ACCEPTED')
```

I am trying to select some memberId's that aren't between 2016 and 2020 but are between 2015 and 2016, however, the query still returns a memberId which is actually between 2016 and 2020

Comment: Redundant checking in date parameter but that's not the issue as you explained. Can you put some sample data from both table and the output you are getting?

Comment: Why not simply `startTime::date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'`? Why did you include 2016-01-01?

Comment: @mkRabbani the output i'm getting are i some memberId's which are just some integers

Comment: Provide some sample data in the question. As you are checking <= '2016-01-01 23:59:59.999', this will include data from 1st January 2016. Is that expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want aggregation:

```
select b."memberId" 
from "shifts" s join
     "bookings" b
     on b."shiftId" = s."id" 
where s."startTime" >= '2015-01-01' and
      b."state" in ('ACCEPTED')
group by b."memberId"
having max(s."startTime") < '2016-01-01' ;
```

Note:  this uses date/times based on the question rather than in your existing query.  You may need to adjust them (I'm not sure why you have January 2nd, for instance in the `WHERE` clause).

This takes all rows on or after 2015, and aggregates by the member id.  The `HAVING` clause selects only members whose maximum date is in 2015.

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4449c36e800390b52097f6b397d67143)

```
WHERE start_time::date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'
```

The `::date` cast truncates the timestamp to its date part. So you do not need to check the times.

Otherwise you can use the `date_part` function to only check the year:

```
WHERE date_part('year', start_time) = 2015
```

---

In your example you included the 2016-01-01 as well. So this would be of course:

```
WHERE start_time::date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2016-01-01'
```

Comment: The cast will prevent it from using the index on that field, if it exists.

Comment: You can create an index on the date ;)

Answer (score 0):

there is no need `"shifts"."startTime" not between '2016-01-02 00:00:00.000' and '2020-01-01 23:59:59.999'` of this condition

```
select distinct 
    "bookings"."memberId" 
from "shifts" 
inner join "bookings" 
on "bookings"."shiftId" = "shifts"."id" 
where  
     "shifts"."startTime" >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
    and "shifts"."startTime" <= '2016-01-01 23:59:59.999' 
    and "bookings"."state" in ('ACCEPTED')
```