# PostgreSQL select dates between dates that aren't between other dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to make some code that basically says 
`SELECT all member ID's from TABLE where state = accepted and date is between 2016 and 2017 and date isn't between 2018-2019`

What I came up with in code is :

```
select distinct "bookings"."memberId" 
from "shifts" 
inner join "bookings" on "bookings"."shiftId" = "shifts"."id" 
where "shifts"."startTime" 
not between '2016-01-02 00:00:00.000' and '2020-01-01 23:59:59.999' 
and "bookings"."state" in ('ACCEPTED')
EXCEPT
select distinct "bookings"."memberId" 
from "shifts" 
inner join "bookings" on "bookings"."shiftId" = "shifts"."id" 
where "shifts"."startTime" >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' and "shifts"."startTime" <= '2016-01-01 23:59:59.999' 
and "bookings"."state" in ('ACCEPTED')
```

If i run this it returns nothing, 0 rows, but if i run the query until the except it returns me rows and then if i take everything after the except it gives me rows too, but when i try to use both with EXCEPT, it fails

Comment: You already opened a quite similar question without answering the question there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56423335/sql-query-doesnt-run-as-intendedbetween/56423515#56423515

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Query doesn't run as intended(between)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56423335/sql-query-doesnt-run-as-intendedbetween)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the two sets must completely overlap, so all rows are missing.  In the first you are taking everything that is not between 2016 and 2020.

This includes all rows that start in 2015.  I would expect it to return members who started before 2015, but perhaps those don't exist.

I answered a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56423335/sql-query-doesnt-run-as-intendedbetween/56425612#56425612) with a simpler query.  You should use that.

Comment: Can you link to the question please?

Comment: @Chris . . . You asked the first question as well.